# Wrong node version used by pnpm in Azure Pipelines

Tags: node.js, azure-pipelines, pnpm

I have been using pnpm in Azure Pipelines for a while now, but recently I've been trying to upgrade to Node 20. But the problem is that pnpm *insists* on using Node 16.20, even when Node 20 is clearly installed.

I've tried installing pnpm both via `npm` as well as `corepack`. They both yield the same result.

**Why is PNPM using Node 16.20, and how can I configure to use Node 20.10?**

My pipeline is configured as follows

```
azure-pipelines.yml

variables:
  pnpm_config_cache: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.pnpm-store

steps:
  - task: UseNode@1
    inputs: 
      version: '20.x'

  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'pnpm | "$(Agent.OS)" | pnpm-lock.yaml'
      path: $(pnpm_config_cache)
    displayName: Cache pnpm

  - script: |
      node -v
      pnpm -v
      corepack enable
      corepack prepare pnpm@latest-8 --activate
      pnpm config set store-dir $(pnpm_config_cache)
      pnpm env list
      pnpm env use --global 20
      node -v
      pnpm -v
    displayName: "Setup pnpm"

  - script: |
      node -v
      pnpm -v
      pnpm install
      pnpm run build
    displayName: "pnpm install and build"
```

This results in the following output, when building:

```
Found tool in cache: node 20.10.0 x64
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/20.10.0/x64/bin
Finishing: Install NodeJs

....

v20.10.0
/home/vsts/work/_temp/d066a5a6-70e7-46d2-8509-9bd3c85af27b.sh: line 2: pnpm: command not found
Preparing pnpm@latest-8 for immediate activation...
v20.10.0
8.12.1
Fetching Node.js 16.20.0 ...
  16.20.0
 ERR_PNPM_CANNOT_MANAGE_NODE  Unable to manage Node.js because pnpm was not installed using the standalone installation script

If you want to manage Node.js with pnpm, you need to remove any Node.js that was installed by other tools, then install pnpm using one of the standalone scripts that are provided on the installation page: https://pnpm.io/installation
v20.10.0
8.12.1

.... (pnpm install step)

v20.10.0
8.12.1
 WARN  Unsupported engine: wanted: {"node":">= 20.10 < 22"} (current: {"node":"16.20.0","pnpm":"8.12.1"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. I found a `.npmrc` file containing this.

```
.npmrc

use-node-version=16.20.0
```